# Wrong formating decimal number while exporting to Excel from RDLC

Tags: c#, rdlc, reportviewer

I'm facing with strange problem while exporting data from RDLC to Excel file.
There are some columns that contains numerical values which are formated like:

**#,0.00**

In report preview the value is correctly showed for example: 8.407,47. Also the same value is correctly exported to excel but when I click in the cell the value is 8.407,474.

I had tried using FormatNumer function but in that case in Excel there is apostrophe added and my number is not any more number but text like '8.407,47

Did I miss something? Is there any way to properly show formated number in exported excel file?

Here are the setting for placeholder:
[image]

And here is what I get after exporting to Excel:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are *formatting* a value, not *rounding* it: so your `DataSet` value probably is `8.407,474` and it is exported to `Excel` without modification, even if it is formatted with 2 decimal digits as you stated in your `rdlc`.

If you don't want to export more than 2 decimal digits, you have to use this function to display a numeric field in your report:

```
=Round(Fields!YourNumber.Value, 2)
```